# React Native Reanimated error: Execution failed for task ':Task :react-native-reanimated:prepareBoost FAILED'

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to run an app on my Android simulator, but I encountered a blocker. The issue seems to stem from this package, preventing the app from running.

Here's the version of the package in question: "react-native-reanimated": "^3.2.0". Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Here's a screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBcBe.png)

I attempted to resolve the issue by navigating to the Android directory and running './gradlew clean', as well as removing the node modules file and rebuilding it. Unfortunately, these steps proved futile.

Comment: The issue has been fixed. Just downgrade to "react-native-reanimated": "2.15.0", so the file boost_1_76_0.tar.gz won't be read anymore because it's unable to read the file format, which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

In `/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build.gradle`

Change this:

```
def srcUrl = "https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/${transformedVersion}/source/boost_${BOOST_VERSION}.tar.gz"
```

To this:

```
def srcUrl = "https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/${transformedVersion}/boost_${BOOST_VERSION}.tar.gz"
```

Make sure to delete the previously downloaded file `boost_1_76_0.tar.gz` in `/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build/downloads`

[Issue Reference](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/5542)